# How to do process substitution together with heredoc

Tags: bash, syntax, heredoc

Want to do:

```
del_comments(){ sed 's/\s*#.*//;/^\s*$/d'; }

readarray -t arr < <( del_comments <<'EOF' )
a       # comm1
b       # comm2
# comm3
c
EOF    
printf "[%s]\n" "${arr[@]}"
```

it complaints about the badly placed 'EOF'. How to write the above correctly?

Want to have `HEREDOC` processed by the `del_comments` function and the result should go to `mapfile` for reading the lines into the array `arr`.

wanted output (from printing the array arr)

```
[a]
[b]
[c]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to write your command is:

```
readarray -t arr < <( del_comments <<EOF
a       # comm1
b       # comm2
# comm3
c
EOF
)
```

Make sure `EOF` is on the line by itself, without any leading or trailing whitespace.

Probably, you need to rewrite your function as:

```
del_comments() { sed 's/[  ]*#.*//; /^$/d'; }
```

- `[  ]` should contain a space and a tab.

Comment: Thanks. :) You solved two problems. :) 1.) the `EOF` has trailing whitespaces 2.) the placement of the `)` **after** the `EOF`.